# instrumentation test for Room

Tags: java, android

"I have a room database and it works normally, I want to test it now but my test doesn't work and I don't see any assert when its run.
in this code Im adding a new record and initializing it, then assert if record is added"

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class PatientDaoTest {
private PatientDao patientDao;
private PatientDatabase db;
public int patient_db_ID;
public int bed_number;

@Before
public void createDb(){
Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, PatientDatabase.class).buil();
patientDao = db.patientDao();}

@After
public void closeDb() throws IOException {
db.close();
}


@Test
public void InsertNewPatient() throws Exception {
PatientRecordEntity newPatient = new PatientRecordEntity();
newPatient.setPatient_db_ID("123456");
newPatient.setPatient_race("chines");
newPatient.setBed_number("123");
newPatient.setReal_bed_number("1234");
newPatient.setRegister_date("5/28/2019");
newPatient.setRegister_time("3:35:02");
newPatient.setPatient_age(12);
newPatient.setPatient_gender(1);

boolean pin = false;
int newRowId = 0;
newRowId = (int) db.patientDao().addNewPatient(newPatient);
if(newRowId == 0){
pin= true;
}

assertTrue("test is true",pin);
}}
```

"It s my Dao query:"

```
@Insert
long addNewPatient(PatientRecordEntity newPatient);
```

"and this is that function that use this query of dao. I don't no if my @test is true or not"

```
public static int AddPatientToDB() {
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
String formatedDate = sdf.format(new Date());
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
String formatedTime = sdf.format(new Date());
PatientRecordEntity newPatient = new PatientRecordEntity();
newPatient.setBed_number(bed_no);
newPatient.setPatient_db_ID(patient_id);
newPatient.setRegister_time(formatedTime);
newPatient.setRegister_date(formatedDate);
int newRowId = 0;
newRowId = (int) pDatabase.patientDao().addNewPatient(newPatient);
current_patient_record_entity = newPatient;
current_patient_record_entity.pid = newRowId;
current_patient_record_entity.sessionID = Repo.currentSessionID;
current_wound_record_entity = new WoundRecordEntity();
current_wound_record_entity.patient_key = (int) newRowId;
current_sample_no = newRowId;

return newRowId;
}
```

Comment: "I don't see any assert when its run" What do you mean? Your test didn't pass or what?

Comment: I mean my test doesn't work or at least I don't know how can I understand is it true or not?  
how should I know it? in log or run or??

Comment: Run -> Run -> choose your test instead of app. Or Alt + Shift + F10. It will open run menu.

Comment: thank you so much, Apparently the problem was from the assert, now it says test passes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"thanks...according to your guide, the test was true and I just modify the assert:"

```
boolean pin = false;
int newRowId = 0;
newRowId = (int) patientDao.addNewPatient(newPatient);
newPatient.setPid(newRowId);
if(0 != newRowId){
pin= true;}
assertTrue("addNewPatient is not true",pin);
```

"and the test passed :))"

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 choices to run your test

1) Run in menu -> Run -> Сhoose your test instead of app

2) Alt + Shift + F10. It will open run menu

3) Click on your test in this menu

[image]

If you want to run all tests of your_project right click on your "test" or "androidTest" folder and choose Run tests in "your_project"

Comment: thanks...whit your guide, the test was true and I just modify the assert:
boolean pin = false;
        int newRowId = 0;
        newRowId = (int) patientDao.addNewPatient(newPatient);
        newPatient.setPid(newRowId);
        if(0 != newRowId){
            pin= true;
        }

and the test passed :))